# Detect when console is being closed?

Tags: c#, .net, console

I googled and found `Console.CancelKeyPress` which is useful and all but many times i close my console by closing the window. Using the X on the top right corner. `Console.CancelKeyPress` detects ctrl+c, how do i detect closing via clicking the X?

Comment: There's lots of help available [at this link](https://www.google.com/#q=detect+when+console+is+being+closed).

Comment: [Detecting Process Exit From Console Application in C#](http://geekswithblogs.net/mrnat/archive/2004/09/23/11594.aspx)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959643/why-does-closing-a-console-that-was-started-with-allocconsole-cause-my-whole-app and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/474679/capture-console-exit-c-sharp and other questions linked to from them.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main( string[] args )
    {
        AppDomain.CurrentDomain.ProcessExit += ProcessExitHandler ;
    }

    static void ProcessExitHandler( object sender , EventArgs e )
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException("You can't shut me down. I quit!" ) ;
    }
}
```

**Edited to note:** apparently, that and most other techniques are gone WRT console apps in Windows 7. The console app is forcibly terminated when the window is closed, so the app never gets signaled. Thx MS!

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/windowscompatibility/thread/abf09824-4e4c-4f2c-ae1e-5981f06c9c6e

The solution seems to be (see above URL) to make your console app a windows app with an invisible window that handles the message `WM_ENDSESSION`, which handler will get 5 seconds to terminate before being shutdown.

Comment: @acidzombie24: apparently, Windows 7 and Vista broke...err...improved things. See my edited answer for details.