# Disable ALT+F4 for C# Console Application?

Tags: c#, .net, c#-2.0

im using c# .net 2.0 Console Application.

How can i prevent my console application from ALT+F4 shortcut?

is there any way to do that?

everywhere there is winform solution.

I need console app solution.

please help me

Comment: Why do you want a standard shortcut to not work for you application?

Comment: You can't. Alt-F4 is handled by the console host, not your application. There is nothing a console application can do to prevent closing of this window, or even do anything in response to it. [See also this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/11959643/4137916), where multiple workarounds are discussed, none of which (I think) work on modern Windows.

Comment: @JeroenMostert consider making this comment into an answer.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert : There is no working methods their that can prevent exiting my console app. i just want to Disable ALT+F4 from exiting my app by user. I think nothing is immpossible. can u tell me actual solution?

Comment: Well sure, nothing is *impossible*. You can inject code into the system processes to alter the behavior of Windows, for example. All you need is administrator permission and a thorough knowledge of system internals... If you're looking for a *realistic* solution, though, it still remains "don't use a console application". You can use a Windows application that spawns a console application and communicates with it through an IPC mechanism, for example (also described in the linked question). The Windows app can detect if the console app is closed. Or you could use a custom control for output.

Comment: Unfortunately I see no reason to disagree with the comment on that question either: that is *also* not possible (in a way that is allowed by documented interfaces). You do seem to have a knack for picking challenges. :P You may want to consider rewriting/reimplementing whatever functionality it is you seek to control here; difficult as that may be, it's probably still less trouble than trying to wrap around it and getting the system to somehow cooperate.

Comment: @Jeroen Mostert : Thanks man! for your imp time for me. Thanks again bro. i will still searching for these two treads answers.

Comment: @JeroenMostert [Far Manager](https://www.farmanager.com/) is a console application, and it does disable Alt-F4 from closing it, so it is certainly possible.

Comment: [conemu](https://conemu.github.io/) does that too.

Comment: @AndrewSavinykh: intercepting Alt-F4 seems to rely on undocumented behavior that I've detailed in my answer. Intercepting the console close, which Far Manager also does (at least partially), is even uglier. Whatever `conemu` does doesn't really count because it is not, itself, a console application -- starting it from the console just opens a new window. It can *host* console applications and customize behavior that way, but that's a completely different kettle of fish, and probably beyond the scope of this question.

Answer (score 2):

@Jeroen Mostert:

i found a final working solution from prevent exiting console app by the user.

Everybody says its not possible. But yes it possible with simple tweak.

Here we go

using C#

```
                RegistryKey objRegistryKey = Registry.CurrentUser.CreateSubKey(@"Console");
                objRegistryKey.SetValue("AllowAltF4Close", "0" , RegistryValueKind.DWord);
```

I cant post my full code here due to copyright

but this code works within my application. I tried to make a sample but that not works. But within my full application this works and Nobody can close by pressing ALT+F4.

this is a real solution for all. I don't know which part is required within my all code to make sample.

but this works.

you can just change value 0 to 1 to enable ALT+F4

CMD will not closing if you use this code. try code and launch another cmd.
i dont need to launch another CMD. within my code that works for itself.

Comment: well, an application changing a system wide well known behavior is quite....  let's say.... annoying?
You are not changing ALT+F4 effect for your application, you are changing it for every console application running on that PC. Acceptable? it depends. Not something nice to the user anyway.

Comment: @Gian Paolo : you can set its value to 1 at the end of application. That will reset original settings. after the application has exited.

Comment: This is what Raymond Chen calls "using global state to solve a local problem". These things are really only an option if you "own" the machine you're running the application on. Consider the scenario where two different applications attempt this, or even two instances of your app -- they're going to be stepping on each other's toes. The other drawback is that this registry setting is not guaranteed to keep working across releases of Windows, and in fact is likely to be removed if enough people start actively abusing it, so keep those caveats in mind.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is "yes, possibly, depending on your version of Windows, but try not to count on it".

At least on my version of Windows 10 (22H2) what works is setting the `ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT` flag using `SetConsoleMode`, while the `ENABLE_PROCESSED_INPUT` flag is cleared (which is normally used to intercept Ctrl-C and Ctrl-Break only).

`ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT` is only documented as "user interactions that change the size of the console screen buffer are reported in the console's input buffer", but experimentally, it also causes Alt-F4 to be treated as regular input rather than a close event (which can then be retrieved using `Console.ReadKey`, for example). Here's how that goes:

```
const int STD_INPUT_HANDLE = -10;
const int ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT = 0x08;

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
static extern IntPtr GetStdHandle(int nStdHandle);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool GetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, out int mode);

[DllImport("kernel32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
internal static extern bool SetConsoleMode(IntPtr hConsoleHandle, int mode);

static void Main() {
    Console.TreatControlCAsInput = true;
    IntPtr stdin = GetStdHandle(STD_INPUT_HANDLE);
    GetConsoleMode(stdin, out var mode);
    SetConsoleMode(stdin, mode |= ENABLE_WINDOW_INPUT);
    Console.CancelKeyPress += (o, e) => {
        if (e.SpecialKey == ConsoleSpecialKey.ControlBreak) {
            Console.WriteLine("Control-Break pressed.");
            e.Cancel = true;
        }
    };
    Console.WriteLine("Press Ctrl-C or Alt-F4 or Control-Break as you please.");
    while (true) {
        var keyInfo = Console.ReadKey(intercept: true);
        if (keyInfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Control && keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.C) {
            Console.WriteLine("Control-C pressed.");
        } else if (keyInfo.Modifiers == ConsoleModifiers.Alt && keyInfo.Key == ConsoleKey.F4) {
            Console.WriteLine("Alt-F4 pressed.");
        } else {
            Console.Write(keyInfo.KeyChar);
            if (keyInfo.KeyChar == '\r') {
                Console.WriteLine();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

For completeness, we also handle Control-Break here, which otherwise still serves as an unconditional interrupt. Note that Control-C cannot be handled by `CancelKeyPress` anymore and must be handled as input.

This trick does not work in the new [Windows Terminal](https://github.com/microsoft/terminal), which may one day replace the default system terminal, nor is it guaranteed to continue working in other versions of Windows.

The only way to stop this application now is terminating it with the close button or the system menu. Completely preventing this from happening would require direct manipulation of the parent window and is not advisable -- consider writing a regular GUI application or a service instead if you really want something to run in the background with full customization.

That said, it is possible to implement custom handling for at least the first close that can run for as long as you like, to implement cleanup. That relies on even more P/Invoking and dirty tricks and is beyond the scope of this question, however -- the basic idea is to use `SetConsoleCtrlHandler` yourself and calling `ExitThread` inside the handler (the .NET `CancelKeyPress` handler will not do for this, because it does not handle `CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT`).

Because none of these approaches will prevent the user from killing your application anyway, and because it relies on undocumented behavior that will almost certainly not be replicated in future versions, I would strongly advise against going this way and implementing a service or regular GUI application instead, or making your console application robust against termination by having it implement cleanup/recovery on startup instead, rather than on exit.