# Win32 Console Application Unexpectedly Terminates with Code 58

Tags: windows, winapi, console-application

On my system, the following code (written in Zig, using [zigwin32](https://github.com/marlersoft/zigwin32) for bindings to the WinAPI) returns the error code 58 after the spawned console is closed:

```rs
const std = @import("std");
const win32 = @import("zigwin32/win32.zig");
const foundation = win32.foundation;
const console = win32.system.console;

// Overrides default behvior, including CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT
fn consoleHandler(_: u32) callconv(.C) foundation.BOOL {
    return 1;
}

pub fn wWinMain(_: foundation.HINSTANCE, _: ?foundation.HINSTANCE, _: [*c]const u16, _: c_int) c_int {
    std.debug.assert(console.AllocConsole() != 0);
    std.debug.assert(console.SetConsoleCtrlHandler(consoleHandler, 1) != 0);

    while (true) {}

    return 0;
}
```

Can someone please explain to me *why* this is happening?

In my mind the program should never stop because there is no explicit `ExitProcess` call and the `while` loop is never exited from. The only way the program can end, I think, is if the console's events run on a separate thread and close the main thread, returning 58, but I'm not sure why or how this is happening.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> In my mind the program should never stop because there is no explicit ExitProcess call

Not by you, no. But there is one, actually. It is being called by the OS.

> The only way the program can end, I think, is if the console's events run on a separate thread and close the main thread

That is exactly what happens. Per the [HandlerRoutine callback function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/handlerroutine) documentation:

> An application-defined function used with the SetConsoleCtrlHandler function. A console process uses this function to handle control signals received by the process. **When the signal is received, the system creates a new thread in the process to execute the function.**

When a console window is closed, it's list of handlers are called for CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, and if any return TRUE (as yours does), the process is terminated immediately.

> The CTRL_CLOSE_EVENT, CTRL_LOGOFF_EVENT, and CTRL_SHUTDOWN_EVENT signals give the process an opportunity to clean up before termination. A HandlerRoutine can perform any necessary cleanup, then take one of the following actions:
>
> - Call the ExitProcess function to terminate the process.
> - Return FALSE. If none of the registered handler functions returns TRUE, the default handler terminates the process.
> - **Return TRUE. In this case, no other handler functions are called and the system terminates the process.**

So, a console handler can't stop its process from being terminated, it can only control whether subsequent handlers are called or not.

Comment: Thanks of the response. Would you mind explaining why the program exits with 58? Also, how can I override this behavior if the handler can't stop the process from being terminated?

Comment: I don't know what the 58 stands for. It's likely a system-defined exit code for the console closing. As for the handler behavior, see this related/dupe post (for C#, but still Win32) : [Why does closing a console that was started with AllocConsole cause my whole application to exit? Can I change this behavior?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11959643/)